# make nginx serve 404 documents relative to current path

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have the following server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name petpal.co.il;
    root /usr/share/nginx/petpal;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /notfound;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What modifications do I need to do in order to make it so the 404 document will be displayed according to the directory the user is currently in, for example in directory "/en" it would display "/en/notfound" and in directory "/" it would display "/notfound"?

Comment: How come no answers? is this question really that complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cnst help, I managed to solve the issue!
Basically all I had to do is put this piece of code outside the php location block:

```
set $lang "";
if ($uri ~ "^/en/") { set $lang "en/"; }
error_page 404 /${lang}notfound;
```

and then inside the php block simply do:

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an `if` would work?

```
set $lang "";
if ($uri ~ "^/en/") { set $lang "en/"; }
try_files $uri /${lang}notfound;
```

Or, if you want a more general rule:

```
set $lang "";
if ($uri ~ "^/([a-z][a-z])/)") { set $lang "$1"; }
try_files $uri /${lang}notfound;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but I get a blank page with No input file specified. message.

Comment: @SaharAtias, sorry, but that doesn't sound like an nginx message!  looks like you've gotten the nginx part working, now just need to make sure your error message page itself exists!

Comment: your second version doesn't work at all for me nginx won't start with it, but anyway I need only the en version for now and i made sure the file /en/notfound exist, it works if i do /someBla it redirects to /notfound but if i do /en/someBla it does No input file specified.

Comment: @SaharAtias, perhaps you can provide the full listing of all the files, in both $document_root and $document_root/en, as well as the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: @SaharAtias, the information from the question is not sufficient to provide any other answer; if you're still trying to figure it out, I'd suggest you eliminate the possible edge cases -- try `notfound.html` in place of what I presume must be `notfound.php`, also you might as well want to replace `try_files` with `error_page 404 /${lang}notfound.html` instead.

Comment: Atm I don't have my server online so I'll have to keep trying later, for now you're awarded with 50 rep for trying to help :)

Comment: @SaharAtias, thanks; and please do clarify in the future where the problem was and how you got it to work

Comment: I still can't get it to work I have no idea what's wrong with it... I tried every way possible like trying notfound.php instead of notfound or using error_page 404 instead of try_files, nothing works.

Comment: Lol! by luck I managed to figure it out, Posted the solution as an individual post as its pretty long.